# Importing csv, using D3.js and Javascript for a Line Graph

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

This is how I import data to create a line chart.
It works fine, but I would like it to work more generally.
Is there a way to replace the `d.v1 = +d.Time` etc lines so they don't have to use the exact name of the Columns (Time, Temp2, Temp3)?

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data){
data.forEach(function(d){
d.v1 = +d.Time;
d.v2 = +d.Temp2;
d.v3 = +d.Temp3;
});
```

I have this code where I am able to read the names of the Columns to label the axis automatically.

```
d3.csv('Messdaten.csv', function(data){  
var headerNames = d3.keys(data[0])      
     xAxisName = headerNames[0];      
     yAxisName1 = headerNames[1];
     yAxisName2 = headerNames[2];
     yAxisName3 = headerNames[3];
});
```

But I wasn't able to use this instead of the exact Name of the Column to create the Diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your question is not exactly clear. However, it seems to me that you are asking something along these lines: *"How to convert strings to numbers without knowing the names of the headers in the CSV?"*.

That being the case, you can use the third argument in the row function, traditionally named `columns`, to iterate through all headers, even if the structure of the CSV is unknown.

First, let's show that in fact we have strings as the default primitive:

```js
var csv = `foo,bar,baz
12,32,44
16,13,64
16,77,42`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv)

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, all the values of `foo`, `bar` and `baz` are strings, not numbers.

Now let's convert them using a general code. We will basically get the headers' names and, using a for loop, iterate over each property:

```
function(d, i, columns) {
    for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
    }
    return d;
}
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var csv = `foo,bar,baz
12,32,44
16,13,64
16,77,42`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv, function(d, i, columns) {
  for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  }
  return d;
})

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, now we have numbers, and we did that without using any header name (`foo`, `bar` and `baz`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!
I think your solution is exactly what I was searching for, but I got some problems using it.

I didn't manage to load extern csv-files. I allways get empty arrays with the length of 0.
Is it the right way to insert the name of the csv-file like below?

    `var data = d3.csvParse("Numbers.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
          for (var i = 0; ... `

Inside the csv-fiile the data has to be formated like this, right?
    `a,b,c,d
    (new line) 1,2,3,4
    (new line) 5,6,7,8`

Comment: No, you have to use `d3.csv`, just like you did in the question, and put the row function between the URL and the callback.

Comment: Allright, one last Question.

I am able to import the data and save them into an array. But how can I access one column of it? Before I had variables for every column `    d.v1, d.v2    `, but now I can't figure out how to do it.

Thank you very much @Gerardo Furtado

Comment: Since this is another issue, please post another question.